# using d3 geomap in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

Trying to use geomap and build a map of USA that I can colour in based on values, but I can't get the map to draw, but it is there (well, the hook workers and data is put in the DIV, can even see the states, but its 0 size.

Started by installing the library

> npm install d3-geomap

Then created an empty new component (TestDraw.component)

Only thing in the html is a div to point d3 to, so my test-draw.componenet.html looks like this

```
<div class="d3-geomap" id="map"></div>
```

Moved the USA.json from node modules to assets (so the browser can get hold of the file)

Added the code to draw the map in ngOnInit

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { select } from 'd3-selection';
import { geomap } from 'd3-geomap';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-draw',
  templateUrl: './test-draw.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-draw.component.css']
})
export class TestDrawComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {


      const USAMap=geomap();
      USAMap.geofile('/assets/USA.json');
      USAMap.scale('1000');
      USAMap.draw(select('#map'));

  }

}
```

And added the CSS to the components CSS

```
@import "../../../node_modules/d3-geomap/dist/d3-geomap.css"
```

It seems happy, it does not complain about the code, and looking at the SVG object, there is data there and I can see state names. But it looks like it hasn't actually drawn it, or maybe drawn it 1px by 1px.

Any ideas

Comment: How big is your `#map` div?  If it's zero size, that would explain the issue.  Try setting a size.  Example: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dimension.asp

Comment: After some more testing, it is actually drawing a perfectly good map. Tested and the above code generates a SVG map, if you inspect the svg, copy it and save it to a .svg file, you can open it and view it

Comment: user2749659: tested it, that seems to be part of the issue, if I make the view bigger (forcing the div to be 500x500 pixels, I get a nice black box) so think if I can set the attrs for d3

Comment: If anyone finds this issue, and I'll post a complete solution later once it works. But the problem was... Black map on black background.... No further comments from me